# Make an element appear at the exact spot of another using transforms

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have an element that I want to appear at the exact spot of another. This other element is transformed in its scale and rotation. The first element must assume the appearance of the other using transforms only.

[image]

```js
const getRotation = el => {
  const st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
  const tr = st.getPropertyValue('transform');

  const values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
  const a = values[0];
  const b = values[1];

  const angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));

  return angle;
}

const firstPhoto = document.querySelector('.first');
const secondPhoto = document.querySelector('.second');

const firstPhotoBox = firstPhoto.getBoundingClientRect();
const secondPhotoBox = secondPhoto.getBoundingClientRect();

const deltaX = secondPhotoBox.left - firstPhotoBox.left;
const deltaY = secondPhotoBox.top - firstPhotoBox.top;
const deltaW = secondPhotoBox.width / firstPhotoBox.width;
const deltaH = secondPhotoBox.height / firstPhotoBox.height;
const deltaR = getRotation(secondPhoto);

firstPhoto.style.transform = `translate(${deltaX}px, ${deltaY}px) scaleX(${deltaW}) scaleY(${deltaH}) rotateZ(${deltaR}deg)`;
```

```css
div {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.second {
  width: 260px;
  height: 400px;
  background: orange;
  transform: translate(20%, 5%) scale(0.8) rotateZ(-2deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">Element 1</div>
<div class="second">Element 2</div>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle demo